# If $n\geq m$ then $(x^m+y^m)^{1/m} \ge (x^n+y^n)^{1/n}$

Tags: inequality, substitution, karamata-inequality

> If $n\geq m$ show that: $(x^m+y^m)^{1/m} \ge (x^n+y^n)^{1/n}$, all numbers being positive real.

Obviously since $n\geq m$, for every $a\in \Bbb Z^+$: $a^{1/m}\geq a^{1/n}$, but does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the transformation of Michael by $x^m=a$, $y^m=b$ and $\alpha=\frac nm$:
$$
x^n=(x^m)^{n/m}=a^\alpha,y^n=(y^m)^{n/m}=b^\alpha.
$$
The inequality is equivalent to:
$$
({a}+{b})^{1/m}\geq ({a}^\alpha+{b}^\alpha)^{1/n}\implies
$$
$$
({a}+{b})^{n/m}\geq ({a}^\alpha+{b}^\alpha)\implies
$$
$$
(\frac{a}{a+b})^\alpha+(\frac{b}{a+b})^\alpha\leq 1.
$$
Now see that for $\alpha>1$:
$$
(\frac{a}{a+b})^\alpha\leq \frac{a}{a+b}.
$$
and
$$
(\frac{b}{a+b})^\alpha\leq \frac{b}{a+b}.
$$

Comment: I don't understand how did you convert the main inequality...

Comment: Hope it is better now...

Comment: @Arash Nice proof! +1

Comment: Thank you dear Arash. Now I get it.+1

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^m=a$, $y^m=b$, $\frac{n}{m}=\alpha$ and $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$.

Thus, $f$ is a convex function because $\alpha\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$(a+b)^{\alpha}\geq a^{\alpha}+b^{\beta},$$
which is Karamata:

Let $a\geq b$.

Thus, since $(a+b,0)\succ(a,b)$, we obtain
$$f(a+b)+f(0)\geq f(a)+f(b)$$
and we are done!

Comment: Do you know any other method?! It should be solvable by more elementary techniques...

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi Draw a graph of $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha\geq1$. Put on $x$-axis points $0$, $b$, $a$ and $a+b$ and draw points $O(0,0)$, $A(a,f(a))$, $B(b,f(b))$ and $C(a+b,f(a+b))$. Since $f$ is a convex function, the midpoint of $OC$ will be above midpoint of $AB$. It's all!